# Cakephp 3.8.6 random image deletion

Tags: php, image, cakephp

I have a cakephp 3.8.6 and i have developed a system to with stores reports. I have reports, images and files.

The problem that i have encountered is that sometimes ( i never know why or when), some images are deleted. The stored image in the server is deleted but in the database the row exists.

The image is uploaded with ajax. And i also upload the files with ajax ( but the files are not deleted, only the images).

I have tried to create a copy of the image in php with the copy command and changing the name (adding a "temp" string before the filename) and display that image instead. But now is that image that is deleted, and the original file is not deleted.

I have thought that could be when the cakephp encounters somekind of error, but i don't know why or if that's whats really happening...

I can't give access to the site or the files...

Any idea of what can be happening?

Thank you in advance. I

Comment: Images are deleted some time after they're saved, or they are deleted immediately on upload?

Comment: some random time after they are saved. I can edit the report, save it again, and edit some times more, view it , edit it again, but at some point it deletes the images. But i don't know why or at what point...

i can edit, save it or generate a pdf from it 20 times and works fine, but at the 21 time, the images are deleted, in other after 5 times,

Comment: When the file is uploaded, you are moving it from the tmp folder to your own folder somewhere, right? When you do that, do you keep the original filename or rename it? If the former, then it might get overwritten when another file with the same name is uploaded? And if you then delete either one of them, the file will be gone for both.

Comment: Yes, i move them from the temp folder to the final folder. The folder to where i move the images is created by the id of the the report, then another folder with the datetime.now and the file name, so it would be unique for each report.

I keep the original file and a copy with the text "cop--" before the name.

Comment: Then I'd have to guess that it's something unrelated to the upload process, like somebody is manually going in and removing files, or something elsewhere is deleting things it shouldn't (search the whole codebase for uses of `unlink`?), or your hard drive is failing.

Comment: I think i found when the problem happens. The image deletion only occurs when cake returns an error... If for example i try to access a field that do not exists or something like that, then cake returns an error ( the usual error page), when this happens, the images are deleted. If no error happens, then the images are not deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens when cakephp encounters an error ( trying to access a non exiting variable, or not finding some data, etc.). When this happens, the images are deleted.

What i did to solve this is first, minimize the errors that can happen.

If the uploaded pdf files have encryption, an error will happen, so if i want the images not to be deleted, what i have done is create a copy of the image before the pdf generation, which is the one that i use for the pdf creation. In case that the pdf generation gives an error, it will delete de copy.

Not that it solves the problem, but at least it will not delete the original files.

Comment: So, in these error cases, it's not actually saving the file at the time of upload? That was the very first question I asked, and you assured us that the file was being saved at that time, and then deleted some time later.

Comment: No, no, the file is uploaded and saved correctly. The file is deleted in other pages, not in the one that upload the file. I have a screen that creates a report, where the files are uploaded and saved. An i have other view which created the pdf file. The image deletion happen on the pdf creation when an error pops.

Comment: Ah, it wasn't clear from any of what you'd said previously that there was any other process happening on the files.